# Nested return function not returning value

Tags: javascript, return-value

I am trying to get the returned value inside the checkValueFunction. When I log the function to the console I get the entire function returned instead of  "This is working." Anyone know why I'm not getting the correct return statement?

```
function checkValueFunction(){
    return function() {
       return "This is working";
    }
}

console.log(checkValueFunction());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your outer function when executed returns the inner function. You need to then execute the inner function to get the "This is working" value.

Try

```
console.log(checkValueFunction()());
```

You see the whole function definition because when you console.log a function that's what it prints.

Comment: Eh, not really. You can do `return () => "This is working"` which is nifty but doesn't really gain you anything here besides being shorter.

Answer (score 0):

`checkValueFunction` will return a function. So you must call the return value of that function.

EDIT: Darn, Paarth was a second before.